# Best practices for batching FB.api requests using the Javascript SDK

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk

I'd like to use the Javascript SDK to make a batch request to FB.api. One of the requests is a standard Open Graph request, the other is a custom Open Graph action.

The following code works but I'd like to know if there's a better, more efficient/simpler method of accomplishing the same.

```
FB.api('/', 'POST', {
    batch:[
        {'method': 'GET', 'name': 'get_info', 'relative_url': 'me?fields=id,first_name,location,picture'},
        {'method': 'POST', 'name': 'post_review', 'relative_url': 'me/oboz-review:review', body: $.param(opts)}
    ]  
    }, function (response){

        var user        = jQuery.parseJSON(response[0].body);
        var post        = jQuery.parseJSON(response[1].body);

    });
};
```

I was hoping the `name` parameter would make it a bit easier to retrieve the results from each request but sadly they don't.

Is there a better method for grabbing the results from each request?

Comment: AFAIK there isn't a "better" solution...

Comment: Bummer. Seems prone to error when making changing or adding additional API requests. Guess I'll just be careful when making changes. Thanks!

Comment: The order of the responses should be exactly the same as the requests. Works on our end at least...